# How Can I auto Populate Room Name in new form of Calendar event in Outllook Web App?

Tags: calendar, office365, sharepoint-online, outlook-web-app

We are using SharePoint Calendar of Office365/OWA to book Conference Room. We are trying to auto-populate the name of Room in calendar event new form.

We have setup a link in our intranet portal, when user clicks on this, it automatically opens the new calendar event form, but we need to auto select specific room.

How can I achieve this? Please provide me suggestions/ideas on this.

Comment: Have not tried it yet but found a solution here if it helps : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588685/ReservationplusofplusresourcesplusinplusSharePoint

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an Outlook web add-in to do this.  Here's a good example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn574750.aspx

But note that there are no events that fire when the new calendar event is created, so you cannot auto-select a room.  But you could simply put a button in your add-in's UI to choose the correct room for the user.